# Find ColumnNames or TableNames as reserved keyword in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have plenty of stored procedures in my database. All are designed to return result sets. I followed naming standards with all keywords are **UPPERCASE** so if any column name or table name as reserved keyword in any of the `SELECT` statement then that would be in UPPERCASE.

I want to convert those UPPERCASE keywords to camel case.

For example one of my actual stored procedures:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prc_getresults
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ZD.Id
        ,ZD.NAME
        ,ZD.TIMESTAMP
        ,ZD.CreatedBy
    FROM ZoneDetails ZD
    INNER JOIN ZONE Z ON Z.Id = ZD.ZoneId
END
```

My expected code after conversion would be

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prc_getresults
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ZD.Id
        ,ZD.Name
        ,ZD.TimeStamp
        ,ZD.CreatedBy
    FROM ZoneDetails ZD
    INNER JOIN Zone Z ON Z.Id = ZD.ZoneId
END
```

Here please look at the column name `TimeStamp`, `Name` and table `Zone`.

There are around 700+ stored procedures. I am unable to open each and every code and edit these manually.

Kindly provide me any ideas to better implement these changes to all stored procedures in the database.

Comment: You need a third party tool to do this. My favorite formatter http://www.dpriver.com/dlaction.php

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the below query for your need,

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       o.name AS Object_Name,
       o.type_desc
  FROM sys.sql_modules m
       INNER JOIN
       sys.objects o
         ON m.object_id = o.object_id
 WHERE m.definition In ( '%\[TimeStamp\]%', '%\[Name\]%', '%\[Zone\]%');
```

Comment: I have given an example but actually I have to check all the keywords....

Comment: Impossible to do this using T-SQL

Answer (score 0):

You'd better download this fantastic free tool - http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/ - The Red-date search for sql server.

Then you have to do some work finding the reserved words - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx

The tool offers you a very good visibility of the things.